# A property of bijective polynomials

Tags: ring-theory, finite-fields

Let $F$ be a finite field and let $f\in F[x]$ be a non-linear polynomial such that it is bijective when considered as a function on $F$. Is it possible that the degree of $f$ divides $|F| -1$ ?

Comment: Its okay to down vote but at least write a reason.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but if I had to guess, it's because it's indistinguishable from a verbatim homework question. People tend to like (or at least, not dislike) questions with a bit of background. Usually that's just a synopsis of what you've discovered about the problem, but there are plenty of things that make a question more palatable.

Comment: At first sight this is non-trivial enough so can't really be a run-of-the-mill homework problem. Voting to leave it open. Do tell us about where you encountered this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polynomials with the property that you want are called **permutation polynomials**. Corollary $1.8$ in http://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.6044.pdf gives you the answer. It's not possible that $\deg f$ divides $q-1$.